# How to save Open Office 365 mail body in database using ASP.Net MVC and SQL Server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, office365, exchangewebservices

How to save Open Office 365 mail body in database using ASP.Net MVC and SQL Server. I have to extract specific mails  and  want to store them in SQL Server .Any code sample will help .

Comment: What have you tried researching? What, in particular, are you struggling with?

Comment: Welcome to SO :-)
Please look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)
and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have got the mail information . If not , please refer to this [demo](https://github.com/OfficeDev/O365-ASPNETMVC-Start) which uses the Office 365 APIs client libraries to demonstrate basic operations against the Calendar, Contacts, Mail, and Files (OneDrive for Business) service endpoints in Office 365 from a single-tenant ASP.NET MVC 5 application.

To save the related information into your database , you could use [Entity Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/data/ef.aspx) in MVC which eliminates the need for most of the data-access code that developers usually need to write.You could click [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) for tutorial about how to use EF6 in MVC5. Check [Entity Framework Development Workflows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178359.aspx#dbfmfcf) to choose between Code First, Database First, and Model First . If you have created table contains email body related columns,  using [EF database first](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/database-first-development/setting-up-database) is an effective way .